# Check condition at second or millisecond intervals

Tags: c, time

I needed to execute a loop and a condition in every second or in the interval of a few milliseconds. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: The question doesn't specify the condition, nor the environment, nor what kind of condition

Comment: I needed the code to be executed on linux platform. Actually it is not a single condition. I have 4 conditions which need to be checked one after another at constant time intervals and the statements need to be executed each time the condition satisfies. I was doing a network chat program in C and i am still not so clear about the conditions.

Comment: See answers : http://www.unix.com/programming/45820-how-periodically-execute-function-c.html

Comment: It is not a single condition. It is a set of conditions. i need to check them one after the other at constant time interval of some milliseconds. Just discovered that in usleep i can get even microsecond precision. How can i use usleep to check one condition after other.

Comment: Do you mean by using a constant time interval, that even if your condition is handled in 50% of the time, you want to make it sleep for the rest of the interval time? Or is it more about making sure that your code is executed in, for an example, 5ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

[usleep](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/usleep/) for POSIX platform (hight precision sleep)

Comment: Can you please tell me the header file to be used for sleep and usleep.

Comment: usleep is obsolete allegedly.  Use nanosleep http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep

Comment: It is not a single condition. It is a set of conditions. i need to check them one after the other at constant time interval of some milliseconds. Just discovered that in usleep i can get even microsecond precision. How can i use usleep to check one condition after other.

Comment: Keep in mind that `usleep`/`nanosleep` do not guarantee that you will resume execution *exactly* after that interval - actually, the scheduler is free to schedule any other process/thread in the meantime, and this means that you may get much bigger delays than you ask for.